# Excel VBA: what is the transforming formula given {X;Y} pair of Chart.MouseDown event to a {Category;Value} pair?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to find formula for transforming X and Y coordinates of `MouseDown`/`MouseUp` event of `Chart` to `Axes`'s coordinate system, i.e to a pair {Category;Value}. Excel Object Model Reference for `Chart.MouseDown` event says:

> The X coordinate of the mouse pointer in chart object client coordinates.

I've found useful methods and properties for the task:

```
Axis: Left, Width
MouseDown/MouseUp: x, y
ChartObject: Left, Width
Application: CentimetersToPoints, InchesToPoints, MeasurementUnit 
Window: ActivePane, PointsToScreenPixelsX, PointsToScreenPixelsY
Pane: PointsToScreenPixelsX, PointsToScreenPixelsY
```

I've also found that X an Y values of a "mouse" event are in pixels -- see test:

```
Private Sub m_target_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
  Dim v_l As Long, v_r As Long
  'X and Y are in pixels!
  With m_target
    v_l = ActiveWindow.ActivePane.PointsToScreenPixelsX(.Parent.Left)
    v_r = ActiveWindow.ActivePane.PointsToScreenPixelsX(.Parent.Left + .Parent.Width)
    Debug.Print "X="; x; "Y="; y; "Xc="; x / 12 * 9; "Yc="; y / 12 * 9; VBA.chr$(13); _
          "xlCategory: Left="; .Axes(xlCategory).Left; " Top="; .Axes(xlCategory).Top; " Width="; .Axes(xlCategory).Width; VBA.chr$(13); _
          "xlValue: Left="; .Axes(xlValue).Left; " Top="; .Axes(xlValue).Top; " Width="; .Axes(xlValue).Width; VBA.chr$(13); _
          "PlotArea: Left="; .PlotArea.Left; " Top="; .PlotArea.Top; " Width="; .PlotArea.Width; " Height="; .PlotArea.Height; VBA.chr$(13); _
          "PlotArea: InsideLeft="; .PlotArea.InsideLeft; " InsideTop="; .PlotArea.InsideTop; " InsideWidth="; .PlotArea.InsideWidth; " InsideHeight="; .PlotArea.InsideHeight; VBA.chr$(13); _
          "ChartObject: Left="; .Parent.Left; " Top="; .Parent.Top; ", Width="; .Parent.Width; " Height="; .Parent.Height; VBA.chr$(13); _
          "ActiveWindow: Caption="; ActiveWindow.Caption; " Left="; ActiveWindow.Left; " UsableWidth="; ActiveWindow.UsableWidth; " Width="; ActiveWindow.Width; VBA.chr$(13); _
          "ChartObject: Left_px="; ActiveWindow.ActivePane.PointsToScreenPixelsX(.Parent.Left); " Width_px="; v_r - v_l
  End With
End Sub
```

The ratio 9/12 was found in ["Excel VBA: Why is so big difference between values returned by PointsToScreenPixelsX for Window and for Pane?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767543/excel-vba-why-is-so-big-difference-between-values-returned-by-pointstoscreenpix)

Clicking right border of a chart gives the following output:

```
X= 1838 Y= 220 Xc= 1378.5 Yc= 165 
xlCategory: Left= 56  Top= 186  Width= 1286 
xlValue: Left= 35  Top= 2  Width= 21 
PlotArea: Left= 34.7092125984252  Top=-4  Width= 1320.84480314961  Height= 210 
PlotArea: InsideLeft= 55.6250393700787  InsideTop= 2.10251968503937  InsideWidth= 1286.32645669291  InsideHeight= 183.845826771654 
ChartObject: Left= 132.374954223633  Top= 0 , Width= 1377.72351074219  Height= 210 
ActiveWindow: Caption=Q99708-VSSPVFGATSSIK-DC-1147-DC-r0001-dn.xlsx Left=-2  UsableWidth= 1279.5  Width= 1298.25 
ChartObject: Left_px=-310  Width_px= 1837
```

`Width_px` is close to `X` and calculated as `v_r - v_l` using converted left (v_l) and right (v_r) border to pixels by `ActiveWindow.ActivePane.PointsToScreenPixelsX`.

But how to find exact formula to get {Category;Value} from {X;Y} which should work for any resolution (pixels per inch), MeasurementUnit, Pane.Left/Width, Chart.Left/Width, PlotArea.Left/Width and Axis.Left/Width?

Comment: I think you want the `Chart.GetChartElement` method.

Comment: @Rory: The Chart.GetChartElement method returns information about the chart element at specified X and Y coordinates instead of a point in {Category;Value} coordinate system. The point is to be used to create new elements on a chart.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. FYI, your 9/12 is the 1 pixel = 0.75 points as mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211293(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @Rory: It is the case for scale of 100% and the method is only of Publisher Application object. For other scale a pixel to point ratio differs. Also in the documentation for the `Application.InchesToPoints` method there is different point definition: *Unit of measure referring to the height of a printed character. A point equals 1/72 of an inch, or approximately 1/28 of a centimeter.*

Comment: A point is always 1/72 of an inch - that doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the formula. The following surprises considerably complicated this:

1. `ChartArea.Width <> ChartObject.Width` and `ChartArea.Height <> ChartObject.Height`!
2. It is possible to move a shape in chart coordinate system out of positive coordinates.

I've created a line shape in a chart and moved line to the left constraint of the chart. And line’s left was -4! Then I've tried to set the `Shape.Left` property to -4. This does not work: its value becomes 0 immediately after assignment. But the `Shape.IncrementLeft` method successfully moved line to the left constraint of a chart (-4). Similarly the `Shape.IncrementTop` method changes a `Shape.Top` property value. As a result a transformation from pixels to points was found.

Then with experiments I've found that `PloatArea.Inside<Left,Top,Width,Height>` must be used instead of corresponding properties of Axis to transform {X;Y} pair in points to a {Category;Value} pair.

First, find shift of ChartArea object in a ChartObject using movement of line shape to left and top constraints:

```
Sub extract_transform(ByVal p_chart As Chart, ByRef p_sh_x As Double, ByRef p_sh_y As Double)
  Dim v_ScreenUpdating As Boolean, v_sh As Double
  With p_chart.Shapes.AddShape(msoLine, 0, 0, 20, 0)
    p_sh_x = 0: .IncrementLeft -10
    While p_sh_x <> .Left
      p_sh_x = .Left
      .IncrementLeft -10 'Move to the left constaint
    Wend
    p_sh_y = 0: .IncrementTop -10
    While p_sh_y <> .Top
      p_sh_y = .Top
      .IncrementTop -10 'Move to the top constaint
    Wend
    .delete 'Collecting garbage
  End With
End Sub
```

Using found {left;top} of ChartArea object in Chart coordinate system a transformation of points to pixels is performed as follows:

```
Sub pixels2points(ByVal p_pane As Pane, ByVal x_pi As Long, ByVal y_pi As Long, ByRef x_pt As Double, ByRef y_pt As Double)
  Dim v_sc As Double
  With p_pane
    v_sc = (.PointsToScreenPixelsX(1000) - .PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)) / 1000
    x_pt = m_sh_x + x_pi / v_sc
    v_sc = (.PointsToScreenPixelsY(1000) - .PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)) / 1000
    y_pt = m_sh_y + y_pi / v_sc
  End With
End Sub
```

The `pixels2points` assumes `x_pi` and `y_pi` are in the chart coordinate system in pixels.
`m_sh_x` and `m_sh_y` are of type `Double` and are members of a class c_report.
`p_pane` is a key object: only `Pane.PointsToScreenPixels<X,Y>` methods transform points to pixels and it depends on scaling factor of a window. Also the same sheet may appear in many windows, hence the corresponding `Pane` object must be used.

To transform {X;Y} pair in points to a {Category;Value} pair a chart wrapper class has the following method:

```
Sub pt2axes(ByVal p_axes As Axes, ByVal p_pa As PlotArea, ByVal x_pt As Double, ByVal y_pt As Double, ByRef p_cat As Double, ByRef p_val As Double)
  With p_axes(xlCategory)
    p_cat = (x_pt - p_pa.InsideLeft) / p_pa.InsideWidth * (.MaximumScale - .MinimumScale) + .MinimumScale
  End With
  With p_axes(xlValue)
    p_val = ((p_pa.InsideTop + p_pa.InsideHeight) - y_pt) / p_pa.InsideHeight * (.MaximumScale - .MinimumScale) + .MinimumScale
  End With
End Sub
```

Transformation formula for Y assumes that the origin of coordinates is at the bottom of a chart.

And now the application of these methods in handling the `Chart.MouseDown` event:

```
Private Sub m_target_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
  Dim v_x As Double, v_y As Double, v_cat As Double, v_val as Double
  With m_target
    Debug.Print "X="; x; "Y="; y
    m_report.pixels2points ActiveWindow.ActivePane, x, y, v_x, v_y
    pt2axes .Axes, .PlotArea, v_x, v_y, v_cat, v_val
    Debug.Print "cat="; v_cat; "val="; v_val
  End With
End Sub
```

`m_target` class member is of type `Chart`. `m_report` class member is of type `c_report` and serves as a reference to a parent object which has the `pixels2points` method.

To test formulas a wide chart, frozen panes and scrolls at scale 400% were used and points at crossing grid lines with visible coordinates {270;2} and {10;6} were clicked. As a result the output of the Immediate window is:

```
X= 6980 Y= 849 
cat= 270.030767164932 val= 2.00522623783961 
X= 564 Y= 522 
cat= 9.97421024128619 val= 6.00822155418118
```

I suppose the difference `+/-0.03` for Category axis occurred because of pixels are discrete and the vertical grid line step had not integer value in pixels.

Comment: Works fine, but only with XY-Diagrams which horizontal axis shows also values. In Diagrams, which have really a category axis, the .MaximumScale and .MinimumScale of this axis will fail because there are no such properties for category axes.

Comment: @AxelRichter: Yes, this task and solution are targeted to XY scatter line charts. I suppose solutions for other chart types should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an approach I just developed today using `GetChartElement` to identify the pixel coordinates where the horizontal and vertical axes are located.  Once those are found, the rest is fairly straightforward.  In my testing it is accurate, on both chart sheets and embedded charts, and does in fact find the pixels coincident with the axes.  The key is to work from the inside out to find each axis.

First code block goes in a Class module named `EventClass`.
Second code block goes in a standard module.

```
Public WithEvents ExcelChartEvents As Excel.Chart

Private Sub ExcelChartEvents_MouseMove( _
        ByVal Button As Long, _
        ByVal Shift As Long, _
        ByVal x As Long, _
        ByVal y As Long)

    Dim oAxis As Excel.Axis
    Dim chtX As Double
    Dim chtY  As Double
    Dim pixAtVertAxis As Long, pixAtHorzAxis As Long
    Dim pts2pix#, pix2pts#, pts2chtX#, pts2chtY#
    pix2pts = PointsPerPixel() / (ActiveWindow.Zoom / 100)
    pts2pix = 1 / pix2pts
    GetPixAtHorizontalAndVerticalAxes pixAtVertAxis, pixAtHorzAxis
    
    Set oAxis = ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
    pts2chtX = (oAxis.MaximumScale - oAxis.MinimumScale) / ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth
    chtX = oAxis.MinimumScale + (x - pixAtVertAxis) * pix2pts * pts2chtX

    Set oAxis = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
    pts2chtY = (oAxis.MaximumScale - oAxis.MinimumScale) / ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideHeight
    chtY = oAxis.MinimumScale - (y - pixAtHorzAxis) * pix2pts * pts2chtY

    Application.StatusBar = "(" & Format(chtX, "#.000") & " , " & Format(chtY, "#.000") & ")"

    If (Shift = 1) Then
        'do this when shift key is held down
        Dim chtID&, arg1&, arg2&
        ActiveChart.GetChartElement x, y, chtID, arg1, arg2
        Application.StatusBar = "(pxX=" & Format(x, "000") & " , pxY=" & Format(y, "000") & ")" _
                            & "  (chtX=" & Format(chtX, "#.000") & " , chtY=" & Format(chtY, "#.000") & ")" _
                            & "  chartID=" & chtID
    End If
End Sub
```

second code block:

```
    Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long

Private Const LOGPIXELSX = 88  'Pixels/inch in X

'A point is defined as 1/72 inches
Private Const POINTS_PER_INCH As Long = 72

Public oChart As EventClass

Public Sub StartCursorReadout()
    'run this to start readout of the mouse location in chart coordinates
    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then MsgBox "First select a Chart or go to a ChartSheet.": Exit Sub
    Set oChart = Nothing
    Set oChart = New EventClass
    Set oChart.ExcelChartEvents = ActiveChart
End Sub

Public Function PointsPerPixel() As Double
'Return the number of Excel points equal to one pixels.  Usually this is 0.6
    Dim hDC As Long
    Dim lDotsPerInch As Long
    hDC = GetDC(0)
    lDotsPerInch = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX)
    PointsPerPixel = POINTS_PER_INCH / lDotsPerInch
    ReleaseDC 0, hDC
End Function

Public Sub GetPixAtHorizontalAndVerticalAxes(ByRef pixAtVertAxis As Long, ByRef pixAtHorzAxis As Long)
    Dim x&, y&, chtID&, arg1&, arg2&, lastchtID&
    Dim pts2pix As Double, success As Boolean
    pts2pix = 1 / (PointsPerPixel() / (ActiveWindow.Zoom / 100))
    With ActiveChart
        success = False: lastchtID = 0
        For y = Int((.PlotArea.InsideTop + .PlotArea.InsideHeight) * pts2pix) - 20 To Int((.PlotArea.InsideTop + .PlotArea.InsideHeight) * pts2pix) - 200 Step -10
            For x = Int(.PlotArea.InsideLeft * pts2pix) + 20 To Int(.PlotArea.InsideLeft * pts2pix) Step -1
                .GetChartElement x, y, chtID, arg1, arg2
                If chtID = xlAxis Then success = True: Exit For
                If chtID = xlChartArea And lastchtID = xlPlotArea Then
                    success = True: x = x + 1: Exit For
                End If
                lastchtID = chtID
            Next x
            If success Then pixAtVertAxis = x: Exit For
        Next y
        success = False: lastchtID = 0
        For x = Int(.PlotArea.InsideLeft * pts2pix) + 50 To Int(.PlotArea.InsideLeft * pts2pix) + 200 Step 10
            lastchtID = 0
            For y = Int((.PlotArea.InsideTop + .PlotArea.InsideHeight) * pts2pix) - 20 To Int((.PlotArea.InsideTop + .PlotArea.InsideHeight) * pts2pix) + 20 Step 1
                .GetChartElement x, y, chtID, arg1, arg2
                If chtID = xlAxis Then success = True: Exit For
                If chtID = xlChartArea And lastchtID = xlPlotArea Then
                    success = True: y = y - 1: Exit For
                End If
                lastchtID = chtID
            Next y
            If success Then pixAtHorzAxis = y: Exit For
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```